# About GenericOptionsParser getRemainingArgs method

Tags: mapreduce

```
package com.ibm.dw61;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

import com.ibm.dw61.MaxTempReducer;
import com.ibm.dw61.MaxTempMapper;


public class MaxMonthlyTemp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        String[] programArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args)
                .getRemainingArgs();
        if (programArgs.length != 2) {
               System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemp <in> <out>");
               System.exit(2);
            }
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Monthly Max Temp");
        job.setJarByClass(MaxMonthlyTemp.class);
        job.setMapperClass(MaxTempMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(MaxTempReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(MaxTempReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(programArgs[0]));

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(programArgs[1]));

        // Submit the job and wait for it to finish.
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }

}
```

Questions :

1) This is a map-reduce code to extract max temperature for each month. The coder is trying to get non-generic options using the getRemainingArgs method. But the next line says if the number of non-generic options is not 2, that means there is an error and the program will immediately abort. I couldn’t figure out what is the coder’s logic here. Anyone kind enough to explain?

2) In another example Wordcount, the coder didn’t perform this step of getting non-generic options. So under what circumstances do we have to perform this step and testing whether the non-generic options numbers 2?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see in the Hadoop API documentation, purpose of the method getRemainingArgs is to extract application-specific arguments , those that are not related to Hadoop framework. in this code, you should specify two arguments, first your input and then output, as you can see in the Usage

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why must these application specific arguments be 2 or otherwise the whole program will abort? One for input and one for output, nothing more nothing less

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why must these application specific arguments be 2 or otherwise the whole program will abort? One for input and one for output, nothing more, nothing less  <------ is this what u meant?

Comment: that isn't related to Hadoop and is only for checking the user input correctness, so you can delete this part of your code without interrupting Hadoop

Comment: String[] programArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args)
                .getRemainingArgs();
        if (programArgs.length != 2) {
               System.err.println("Usage: MaxTemp <in> <out>");
               System.exit(2);

Comment: this whole chunk can be deleted?

Comment: you can remove the if condition

Comment: i see. Thanks so much! :)